# apt-get upgrade not working anymore

Tags: apt, filesystem, dpkg

I'm trying to reinstall Raspbian Stretch Lite version to make a fresh install on my Rpi 2 B. 
I use to follow the every same steps everytime I do this;

```
sudo raspi-config //to expand file system 
reboot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

the downloads end well then when it tries to install the packages this is what I've got:

```
... 
Preparing to unpack .../23-firmware-brcm80211_1%3a20161130-3+rpt3_all.deb ...
    Unpacking firmware-brcm80211 (1:20161130-3+rpt3) over (1:20161130-3+rpi2) ...
    Preparing to unpack .../24-firmware-libertas_1%3a20161130-3+rpt3_all.deb ...
    Unpacking firmware-libertas (1:20161130-3+rpt3) over (1:20161130-3+rpi2) ...
    Preparing to unpack .../25-firmware-misc-nonfree_1%3a20161130-3+rpt3_all.deb ...
    Unpacking firmware-misc-nonfree (1:20161130-3+rpt3) over (1:20161130-3+rpi2) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-79ke7I/25-firmware-misc-nonfree_1%3a20161130-3+rpt3_all.deb (--unpack):
     unable to clean up mess surrounding './lib/firmware/nvidia/gm20b/acr/bl.bin' before installing another version: Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_nonctx.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_method_init.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_ctx.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_sig.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_inst.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_data.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/gpccs_bl.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_sig.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_inst.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_data.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/gr/fecs_bl.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/ucode_unload.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/ucode_load.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm206/acr/bl.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_nonctx.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_method_init.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_ctx.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_sig.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_inst.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_data.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/gpccs_bl.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_sig.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_inst.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_data.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/gr/fecs_bl.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/ucode_unload.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/ucode_load.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm204/acr/bl.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_nonctx.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_method_init.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_ctx.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/sw_bundle_init.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_sig.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_inst.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_data.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/gpccs_bl.bin': Read-only file system
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
     unable to restore backup version of '/lib/firmware/nvidia/gm200/gr/fecs_sig.bin': Read-only file system
```

There is nothing I do different from the other times... And I tried it with different SD Cards.

This time everything works but when it comes to the upgrade I got errors.

I'm completely lost so I asked for your advises.
Thank you for reading, I hope someone will sort me out of this

Comment: What OS? You say "trying to reinstall the OS" - **WHAT** did you **ACTUALLY** do?

Comment: I use Raspbian Stretch. my pi is running a homekit server as main function

Comment: **DO NOT** post detail in your question - **NOT** comments. "running a homekit server as main function" is **NOT** what **YOU** did - did you do a fresh install? What commands did you enter?

Comment: Yes I made a fresh install as always. I flash my card using Etcher with official Raspbian image. 
Then the steps are:
sudo raspi-config ===> expand file system
reboot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade and this is where I'm stuck

Comment: as always? do you do fresh installs regularly? why?

Comment: the "Read-only file system" question seems to be a popular question on stack exchange recently...

Comment: yes, i'm constantly trying new things and when I'm surrounded with bugs I do a fresh install to keep only what worked before

Comment: have you tried a new sd card? That's what I'd do - also try `dmesg` - see if there's anything in that output to indicate what has happened

Comment: Yep I did...After the upgrade fail, I can'nt do anything. The pi tell me -bash command not found